# How to get uploaded file local path in react js using hooks

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, path, react-hooks

When i upload the image,  in  console it shows that it is blob and can't find file , I just want to see the file's local path in  console

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function FileUpload() {
    const [file, setFile]=useState(null);

    const uploadSingleFile= (e) =>{
        setFile( URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
    };
    const  upload= (e)=> {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(file);
    };
    let imgPreview;
    if (file) {
        imgPreview = <img src={file} alt='' />;
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <form className="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                <div className="form-group preview">
                    {imgPreview}
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="file" className="form-control" onChange={uploadSingleFile} />
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={upload}>Upload</button>
            </form >
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: your code seems to consisit of only code add plase some explanation what you want to get.

Comment: When i upload the image,  in  console it shows that it is blob and can't find file , I just want to see the file's local path in  console

Answer (score 0):

For security reason browser won't allow to have exact path for your file, you can only have access to fake path using `value` property of target for [fake path](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_value.asp)